# text input get filename on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, filenames

I have an html form to write some filenames but its kinda lame to just write each filename in the form for everything that i will submit in the form. So i thought of a better idea which would be to just drag a filename of top of my text input and the text input's value changes to the name of the file. I know that i can specify file in the type attribute in the input but that's for uploading files. I dont want to upload anything. I only want to get the filename thats why i have a text input.

So, Im looking for either jQuery or Javascript solution to this problem. Unfortunately i dont have alot of code to share but i show an example of a form. I know this will be disliked because i dont share any javascript code but i don't even know where to begin and this is the only place i know to find out. So i'm sorry for that.

But here is the html form example

```
<form action="somefile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="mpqfile" placeholder="mpq filename">
    <input type="text" name="sqlfile" placeholder="sql filename">
    <input type="text" name="objfile" placeholder="obj filename">
    <input type="text" name="m2file" placeholder="m2 filename">
    <input type="text" name="skinfile" placeholder="skin filename">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: How will drag the filename ? Is it available somewhere on the computer somewhere and you want select and drop it in your input ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes that's correct. The files are on my computer and i want to drag them from a folder on my computer on to the input in the website to get the filename in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each textbox you can define the drop zone around some parent DIV/Container.

*`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop`*

You can access the file name using **ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name** in your drop handler. After you get the name of the file you can set the value of the respective textbox to the file name.

```
document.getElementsByName("mpqfile").value = filename;
```

Comment: I can only get that to work for 1 input. But as seen in the form above there are more inputs. So i'm still having some trouble with this but i'm thankful for the information, It has atleast pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Will you be able to identify the text box where the value has to be written from a filename? If yes...you can create a single drop zone around all the text boxes and write the value in the respective text box based on the file name. A user will be able to drag multiple files at once and in the drop handler you can iterate through all the files, find file name, identify the text box and write the value in the respective textbox.

Comment: I found a solution. I edited the function to take 2 values. Before it was ondrop="dropHandler(event); and i changed it to ondrop="dropHandler(event, 'mpqfile'); to get the id of the input. I tried getting the id using this.getAttribue("id"); but that didnt really work... But now i got it all to work. Thanks. I can rework this now and make it better

Answer (score 1):

You may refer the following URL:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop